# How to run crontab for first time with no user intervention

Tags: bash, cron

I am attempting to run the command below in an installation script.  The first time this command runs, it prompts me to select an editor and then I have to save the file manually.  Here is the command:

```
crontab -u www-data -e
```

How do I make it so that I don't need user input at all?

It should just take default: nano, saves the file, & exists nano.

Comment: The command you wrote only makes sense in an interactive run. What do you actually want to do? Perhaps also checkout http://xyproblem.info/ .

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the cron file directly -->

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/your_user
```

Then restart cron gracefully

```
sudo service cron reload
```

Answer (score 0):

or even just a crontab edit

```
crontab -e
```